# Prepared statment to test which field is wrong with username or password

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Checking to see if a record has matches with a WHERE is pretty common.  But I was wondering this morning  if it would be possible to discover if you had a partial match.  If so, which one is right and which is wrong?  So the user_name might be correct but not the email address.

Is there a way to do that without doing two different query statements?  This is my starting code.  Suggestions?

```
  $query = "SELECT user_name, user_email FROM user_list WHERE (user_name = ?) AND (user_email = ?)";
  $stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $query);
  mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'ss', $username, $email);

  if ($result = mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)); 
    {
      mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $db_username, $db_email);
      $got_match = mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);    
      }
```

I'd appreciate if the answers were in a procedural method.  :-)

Comment: Not using `execute();` ?

Comment: Best practice would say not to let the end user know if the username is correct when the password is wrong as this could help with hacking attempts.

Comment: Better **not** tell if there was a partial match, or you could be saying to a potential attacker that they guessed something right.

Comment: try changing the AND to an OR in your sql query.  The only risk is if there is more than one record for either an email address or username

Comment: Good point, it might not be a good idea to tell.  However I'm curious to know though.

Comment: While I certainly understand the sentiment, I disagree with the absolute that all logins should not indicate if a match was made with the singular username/email. If you properly implement a system to prevent bruteforcing of passwords, users of your system will be grateful to have the ability to "guess" their own usernames. How many times have you gone to some website you barely use, only to have to now check your email and click the link for lost username IN ADDITION TO checking your email and clicking the link for a lost password. Make an informed decision instead of following the herd.

Comment: Why isn't the query checking the password? It's just checking username and email.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well first of all, you would need to use an OR condition in the where clause for partial matching:

```
WHERE user_name = ? OR user_email = ?
```

Second, you would like need to add some CASE statements (or IF statements if you like) in the select to determine which items match:

```
SELECT
  user_name,
  (CASE WHEN user_name = ? THEN 1 ELSE 0 END CASE) AS user_name_match,
  user_email,
  (CASE WHEN user_email = ? THEN 1 ELSE 0 END CASE) AS user_email_match
```

So putting it all together

```
SELECT
  user_name,
  (CASE WHEN user_name = ? THEN 1 ELSE 0 END CASE) AS user_name_match,
  user_email,
  (CASE WHEN user_email = ? THEN 1 ELSE 0 END CASE) AS user_email_match
FROM user_list
WHERE user_name = ? OR user_email = ?
```

Note that you would need to bind to all 4 parameters.

As others have pointed out in the comments above, if your intent here is to tell the end user if only user_name or user_email match, this is probably not a good idea from a security standpoint.

Comment: You don't need `CASE` or `IF`, you can just use `SELECT user_name = ? AS user_name_match`.

Comment: @Barmar A good suggestion.  I typically like to be more explicit when defining such conditional values in a query, thus am in the habit of using CASE/IF.

Comment: I don't plan to give them the information.  However the method on how to do this is still interesting.  However, I've never used `SELECT AS` before.  New one for the newb.

Comment: @user2070436 How can you never use `AS`? What do you do when you have to compute something in a `SELECT` statement? Don't you need to give it an alias? Note that the `AS` keyword is optional, you can write `SELECT <expression> <alias>`

Comment: Newb Barmar.... newb.  Everybody has to start somewhere.  Where can I read about `AS`?

Comment: AS is an alias so you can give your column names an alias